# What do I need to know about Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

I am currently trying to pick up the frustrating world of common lisp.  Before I get too deep into this and get too angry at the computer could anyone give me pointers on what to expect and general tips/tricks.

Thanks

Comment: Be patient and don't try to apply your algol knowledge to fasttrack since it doesn't work. Go through a book as if it;s your very first programming language.

Comment: Common lisp is not frustrating,it is a programmable programing language and a great adventure to learn that will convert you in a better developer. Take a look here http://eudoxia.me/article/common-lisp-sotu-2015 and then pick also a good book like ANSI Common Lisp from Paul Graham and enjoy the journey

Answer (score 4):

Great question. Since I am quite new to lisp too, and the hurdles are still fresh I think I can offer some help. Here a few tips in no particular order. I might add more if I think of them.

1) Understand how lists are implemented in lisp.

2) Read [Land of Lisp](http://landoflisp.com/) by Conrad Barski.

3) Understand the difference between read time, compile time and run time. (If you don't you will never "get" macros)

4) Symbols and packages. Packages are all about namespacing/exporting/shadowing symbols. (At least for me). Check [this](http://www.flownet.com/gat/packages.pdf) out. (I know, the title sucks, but the content is good.) You can think of symbols as identifiers for functions and variables. Common lisp is a Lisp 2. Read about that. If the symbol is inside parenthesis common lisp will look for the function definition of the symbol and if it is not - for the variable definition. Look up how symbols are implemented internally. ([ANSI common lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/acl.html) by Paul Graham has a great chapter on that)

5) Macros operate on code. Read [On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisptext.html) by Paul Graham when you feel ready. It is considered the seminal work on macros.

6) For truly beautiful lisp code I suggest [Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming](http://norvig.com/paip.html)

7) CLOS is the Common Lisp Object System. The book that really helped me "get" CLOS is [Object-Oriented Programming in Common Lisp](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201175894). It is old (older than myself in fact) but totally relevant and worth it. Read about dynamic dispatch. The Meta Object Protocol is still something I am trying to figure out so I cannot give you a lot of tips there :(

8) An "Alist" or "associative list" is just a list of lists. However common lisp has build-in operators for it like `assoc` (for finding an item in the list) There are also proper list, dotted list, property list (or plist). There are also operators like `union` that will treat an ordinary list like a set. Lisp is all about this sorts of abstraction. If you have an idea that a particular list will behave like a set then you don't need to implement a set data structure. When you start developing with lisp you will find yourself cutting corners like that all the time.

9) `setf` is a "generic setter". It is nice to have one operator for setting the values in arrays, lists (or alists, etc...), slots (the word for fields in an object) etc... we can use the same command.

The best advice is just read read read. It is not that hard of a language really.

And just a tip for when you are delving in a new technology: Create a file `research.md` where you write everything new that you learn. Like a journal. Works great for me.

And don't get frustrated :) Google the error messages or ask for advice in [#clnoobs](http://www.cliki.net/IRC)